# React + Bootstrap + Bootstrap downloaded Theme

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I would like to integrate this theme https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/new-age/ , inside a new React app using create-react-app.

Can someone enlighten me? I am bit confused about how to start with this.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. There's [a template](https://github.com/wzuo/react-startbootstrap-new-age) without using create-react-app.
2. Using `create-react-app` is nothing special

> npm install -g create-react-app
>
> create-react-app new-age-demo
>
> cd ./new-age-demo
>
> npm install bootstrap startbootstrap-new-age

add the following to the top of `src\index.js`

> import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
> import 'startbootstrap-new-age/css/new-age.css';
>
> import $ from 'jquery';
> window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
> require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');
> require('jquery-easing');
> require('startbootstrap-new-age/js/new-age.min.js');

then take [this markup](http://view-source:https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/) as an example and put the content of a `body` tag to your `App` component (with some adjustment like removing comments, adding self-closing tags, refactoring into components)

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for the reply. Although it is not fully working. I created the react app, install dependencies and added the code to src/index.js. And it appears this error: `TypeError: a(...).offset(...) is undefined
e
node_modules/startbootstrap-new-age/js/new-age.min.js:1`

Comment: I managed to make it working removing the last lines of Import $ from ... to require('startbootstrap... etc) . what are the use of those?